# When is $R^{op}\cong R$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Suppose $R$ is a noncommutative ring. When could I reasonably expect $R^{op}\cong R$?

For instance I know group rings have a natural involution, i.e. if $SG$ is the group ring in question then $r\cdot g=g^{-1}\cdot r$. Does this imply $S[G]^{op}\cong S[G]$? If so, does this apply to any ring with a natural involution?

Finally, does $R^{op}\cong R$ imply all left ideals are right ideals (and vice versa)?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I meant for the coefficient ring to be commutative

Comment: In the last case, consider $R = M_2(A)$ for $A$ commtuative. Then the map $g \to g^t$ is an isomorphism $R \to R^{\text{op}}$, but $R$ has one-sided ideals; consider the set of matrices of the form $$g = \begin{pmatrix}* & * \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ for example.

Comment: @anomaly Thanks for the counterexample. I was thinking of considering ideals as modules. Since any left module is a right module over its opposite ring, I expected left ideals to equal right ideals. Why exactly is this failing?

Comment: @SamWilliams Thinking that this means all left ideals must all be right ideals is just non-sequitur. Yes, all of the left ideals correspond to right ideals via the isomorphism. *And* all left ideals that aren't right ideals correspond to right ideals *that aren't left ideals.* The example above shows precisely why. The nontrivial one-sided ideals form two disjoint sets, and they correspond to each other via the transposition map.

Comment: @SamWilliams: For one thing, the action of $R$ and $R^\text{op}$ are not the same. You can use an isomorphism $R\to R^{\text{op}}$ to transform a left $R$-module into a right $R$-module, but the induced map on modules is not trivial.

Comment: You say that in a group ring $S[G]$, $r\cdot g=g^{-1}\cdot r$ for any $r\in S[G]$, $g\in G$. Why would this be true in general? If we take $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $g=5$, $r=3$, $r+g=3+5=8\neq -2 =-g+r$